# ‘so there!’ (an expression of defiance)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

The context this expression is used in is as an additional phrase to the main sentence and emphasises that you will not change your mind about a decision you have made. The phrase is generally spoken in a tone which is somewhat rude, angry, defiant or childish.
Examples are:-
-No, I won't help you, so there!
-Well, I don't want to be your friend, either. So there!
-My essay was better than yours, so there!
I cannot think of any Latin equivalent idiom or interjection and wonder if a ready idiom is to hand that colleagues can suggest. My examples need to be properly formatted but I lack the necessary expertise!

Comment: Could we just say "I don't care." "Who cares? The verb "refert" means something like this:

Comment: ‘Who cares?’’ means something like ‘so what’ rather than ‘so there’. The first idiom indicates indifference, whereas ‘so there’ which is defiant.

Comment: I guess only a native will be able to help you. I never heard of "so there" I had to google it and the meaning in Portuguese is like "have in mind!" "Did you understand that?" I just suggest that because the thesaurus says it's a way of saying that you don't care.

Comment: If I understand well, it substantially means something like *Make your peace with it!* (French "Prends-en ton parti!") I believe this very concise expression, formed out of two extremely common grammatical words, could correspond to French *c'est comme ça* "it is what it is". *Ita est.* could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you , Manuel and Vincent! The expression in an  earlier form was ‘so put that in your pipe and smoke it!’  Maybe it is similar to, but not identical with, the Latin ‘velis, nolis (with corresponding change of person):- ‘like it or not!’ A French equivalent is si ça ne te plaît pas, c'est le même prix. In Spanish it is ¡chúpate esa! or ‘ si quieres créetelo, si no quieres no’. Three German equivalents  can be found at https://en.pons.com/translate/english-german/put+that+in+your+pipe+and+smoke+it. It has an offensive nuance, absent from ‘that’s the way it is’.